# Remove a row from uBlas compressed matrix?

Tags: c++, boost, numerical-methods, ublas

I was wondering what was the best way to remove a row from uBlas's compressed matrix? I was wondering if there was some way to get a hold of the compressed column data inside the vector? I am looking at this page http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html and can't find how to access those elements.

My matrix is declared as follows:

```
  ublas::compressed_matrix
     <
     double,
     ublas::column_major,
     0,
     ublas::unbounded_array<int>,
     ublas::unbounded_array<double> >
```

My eventual goal is to use this method to remove all zero rows.

**EDIT:**
I suspect the solution will involve changing the ublas::compressed_matrix structure internally. I think its safe to assume that the number of non-zero entries will be on the order of 1k. I hope to call the method to remove a row, maybe, 20 times.

Comment: is a proxy an acceptable alternative? removing row is non-trival.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by a proxy.

Comment: and ublas don't use std::vector for storage

Comment: Matrix Proxies http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_proxy.htm , to be specific, the "Matrix Slice" object

Comment: I wouldn't have any problems using matrix proxies, but I don't quite see how it can help me remove a row in the middle of the matrix.

Comment: > I hope to call this method, maybe, 20 times.  
which one exactly? removing a row or removing all the zero rows?